# Program side mouse buttons without additional software?

Tags: windows-10, mouse

I have an LG 603 mouse at home and I use the Logitech gaming software to switch my side buttons to copy and paste.  I want to use this as my work mouse and retain the copy/paste ability.  Is there a way to do this without installing (likely not-allowed) software on my work computer? I've tried to use the on-board memory profiles, with no success.

Comment: Are you allowed [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) or [AutoHotkey Portable](https://portableapps.com/node/39299)?

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure you cannot do this without using the software supplied to change and use the functions.

I have LogiTech software here on my laptop. t requires the software and it needs Admin Credentials to install.

So you will need to see if your work System Administrator will install the mouse for you. There is a reasonable chance he or she might install it for you.

Comment: This does not answer the author’s question.  They specifically indicated they want to accomplish this without installing Logitech software